# Problem with Newton's Method in solving a System of Equations

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I'm trying to use Newton's method to solve the following system of equations, where f and g are functions of x and y. (h,a,f,c,d,b and k are just constants).

$f(y,x)=\left[\begin{array}{c}
y^{1}\\
y^{2}\\
y^{3}\\
y^{4}
\end{array}\right]-\left[\begin{array}{c}
y_{0}^{1}\\
y_{0}^{2}\\
y_{0}^{3}\\
y_{0}^{4}
\end{array}\right]+h\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{1} & f_{1} & 0 & 0\\
c_{1} & a_{1} & f_{1} & 0\\
0 & c_{1} & a_{1} & f_{1}\\
0 & 0 & c_{1} & a_{1}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
y^{1}\\
y^{2}\\
y^{3}\\
y^{4}
\end{array}\right]+\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
b_{1} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
d_{1} & b_{1} & 0 & 0\\
0 & d_{1} & b_{1} & 0\\
0 & 0 & d_{1} & b_{1}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
x^{1}\\
x^{2}\\
x^{3}\\
x^{4}
\end{array}\right]-\left[\begin{array}{c}
k_{1}\\
0\\
0\\
k_{2}
\end{array}\right]=0$

$g(y,x)=\left[\begin{array}{c}
x^{1}\\
x^{2}\\
x^{3}\\
x^{4}
\end{array}\right]-\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_{0}^{1}\\
x_{0}^{2}\\
x_{0}^{3}\\
x_{0}^{4}
\end{array}\right]+h\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{2} & f_{2} & 0 & 0\\
c_{2} & a_{2} & f_{2} & 0\\
0 & c_{2} & a_{2} & f_{2}\\
0 & 0 & c_{2} & a_{2}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
y^{1}\\
y^{2}\\
y^{3}\\
y^{4}
\end{array}\right]+\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
b_{2} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
d_{2} & b_{2} & 0 & 0\\
0 & d_{2} & b_{2} & 0\\
0 & 0 & d_{2} & b_{2}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
x^{1}\\
x^{2}\\
x^{3}\\
x^{4}
\end{array}\right]-\left[\begin{array}{c}
k_{1}\\
0\\
0\\
k_{2}
\end{array}\right]=0$

Am I right in saying that the Newton Iteration equations be:

$y^{k+1}=y^{k}-\frac{f(y,x)}{\frac{\partial f(y,x)}{\partial y}}$
and $x^{k+1}=x^{k}-\frac{g(y,x)}{\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial x}}$.

Or would the denominators be partial derivatives: $\left(x\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+y\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)$.

I know it was not necessary to write the entire functions but I have some more questions about the equations depending on the answer to this one.

Many Thanks!

Comment: I've just been thinking a lot about this and realized that I'm not even sure how I can apply Newton Raphson method to these equations. If applying it to the first equations will give x or y? ... Please help if have any ideas.

Comment: Note: It's very possible I'm horribly wrong. With that said:

I've never seen Newton's method applied to functions that aren't single variable. http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsMethod.html

Mathworld does not seem to recognize this approach, either. Sorry if I am wrong, but I think Newton's method does not apply to functions that are more than one variable.

Comment: There's a method called the Multivariate Newton Raphson Method (MNRM) which is used for functions of more than one variable. But my equations are a bit more complicated. So I'm not quite sure how this could be applied in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Your equations amount to a   system of $8$ scalar equations with $8$ scalar unknowns. Writing  $x$ and $y$ as separate vectors is not helping clarity here. Stack them into one $8$-dimensional vector $z$, and similarly stack $f$ and $g$ into one function $h$. Formally speaking, the equation $h(z)=0$ could be solved by the Newton-Raphson method as
$$
z_{n+1} = z_n - (Dh(z_n))^{-1} h(z_n)
$$
... except this is pointless/tautological when the system is linear. Whatever the starting point is, you get the solution after one step of iteration. Indeed,  the Newton-Raphson method amounts to approaching the root by replacing the given system with its linearization around a previously found point, and solving the linear system to find the next approximation. Your system is linear to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is a matrix with two unknowns and four equations. This implies that there isn't *necessarily* a consistent solution. However, if you are trying to find the nearby local optima solution, you can use a computational method called gradient descent. It is a multivariable analog to Newton's Method. It works a finite (sometimes adaptive, depending on algorithm) step size.

The recurrent equation is:
$$\vec x_{i+1}=\vec x_i - h*\vec \nabla f(\vec x)$$
$h$ is the step size, and is usually small. There are advanced techniques for computing the "optimum" step size in a given situation, but the techniques are often not worth the added calculation complexity. As the system gets close to a solution, the gradient often becomes unstable due to numerical conditioning. As a result, it tends to bounce around the actual solution in random directions. However, at this point, the solution found is usually close enough for practical purposes.

Comment: Since $x,y,f,g$ have four components each, there are $8$ scalar unknowns and $8$ scalar equations.